# jQuery/Css : A pop-up content Div pushes the page down

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am using a jQuery plugin called [Reveal](http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin). It just shows a div like a pop-up when you click a link with specific class.

In my website I am using this for showing comments. The problem is that when the content of div is a lot, the opened div pushes the bottom of page.

[image]

Is there a jQuery or Css way to make unwanted space be gone after comment div is closed ?

**Edit 1**: This is the closing animation code:

```
modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                            modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden'});
                            unlockModal();
                        });
```

**Edit 2**: If I use scrolling, this is what happens:

normal : http://jsfiddle.net/K4E3g/1/

scrolling : http://jsfiddle.net/K4E3g/2/

Comment: Could you make the comments scrollable by adding a css overflow rule? Or, is this not desired design?

Comment: Is the box being set to display:none when hidden, and is the box positioned absolutely?

Comment: @ElGuapo I don't have enough space for that, and that will somehow mess up the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited**

The plugin uses `visibility: hidden / visible` to show and hide a modal extensively throughout its code. This means that any modal in its closed state is set to `visibility: hidden`, which has the effect that, if the modal is larger than the page, making the page longer than it should be, as elements with `visibility: hidden` still take up space on the page.

You can either try changing all the `visiblity: hidden` to `display: none` and `visibility: visible` to `display: block` in the plugin itself and see if that gets you the desired result, however I have not tested this and there may be undesirable side effects.

Alternatively, I would suggest looking at a different modal plugin such as Eric Martin's excellent [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) plugin.

I hope this helps!

Comment: If this is the correct way to do this you could smooth out the process by animating the height to 0 before removing the comment div.

Comment: It is the same as before, the unwanted space is still there

Comment: @xperator can you post a snippet of your HTML?

Comment: @dSquared What you mean by snippet ? (sorry for my english)

Comment: @xperator answer updated; unfortunately without editing the plugin extensively I believe you will continue to run into this problem.

Comment: @dSquared Thanks a lot. I changed every `visibility` to `display` and the unwanted space doesn't show up anymore!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to target the created modal div with CSS and give it a max-height value and a max-width value, and overflow:scroll.

Something like this should work:

```
div.comments-modal {
  max-width:60%;
  max-height:80%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

*NOTE: using % values instead of px values will allow your modal's dimensions to adjust with the user's browser/screen size. If you want to prevent that, then simply use px defined values instead.*

Comment: As I told ElGuapo, it will mess up the modal div design.

Comment: Check the edited question, You can now see how scrolling works.

Comment: Well if you want to avoid the text getting cut off, simply add an extra wrapper and change the positioning a bit, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/K4E3g/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `max-height` and `overflow: auto`

```
    #myModal {
        max-height: 300px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
         <h1>Modal Title</h1>
         <p>Any content could go in here.</p>
         <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
```

Or, you can try

```
modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                        modal.animate({
                            "top":  $(document).scrollTop()-topOffset + 'px',
                            "opacity" : 0
                        }, options.animationspeed/2, function() {
                            modal.css({'top':topMeasure, 'opacity' : 1, 'display' : 'none'});
                            unlockModal();
                        });
```

You could also try using a fade-in animation that will animate the height of the div from 0 to 100%, then scroll back up as it fades in opacity.

**EDIT:** Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BkZ6k/) for an example using just jQuery.

Comment: How to do that scroll back up? That's what I am trying to do, I want to make the unwanted space be gone and scroll back up to page.

Comment: @xperator check the edit and http://jsfiddle.net/BkZ6k/.  Just remember to set your browser size so you can see the effect of setting `display: none` versus `visibility: hidden`.